# Fatal error: Class Model\some_model not found GAS-ORM CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, google-apps-script

my codes of CodeIgniter Gas-ORM are running well on Windows 7 with php 5.4.3 but on the go daddy host it is generating error that says

`Fatal error: Class 'Model\Currency_model' not found in /home/kamaroly/public_html/kpos2/application/libraries/Sale_lib.php on line 433`

on line 433, codes are below

```
$dafault_currencies= Model\Currency_model::limit(1,0)->find_by_Default(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have correct it, 
I had to rename all the names spaces and write them in lower case , i had declared my name space like `namespace Model;` and now I changed it to `namespace model;`